# How do I use AdMob in a libGdx game?

Tags: java, android, libgdx, admob

I have been tryig to implement adMob with libGdx but I either start getting errorsor the app crashes when I run it on my phone. There seem to be a lot of out of date information so I cant follow a tutorial properly. also another thing I dont understand is, when you add the adMob stuf in the MainActivity class, how can you show and hide adds? I have leaderboards implemented and there is an interface class which I can use to to interact with the leaderboards so is it the same with adMob as well? Can someone please point me to an up to date and easy to follow guide.
I have tried a official guide from google but I get an error at the point (R.layouts.main_actitivy)

I get red squiggly lines under this line. what does this mean and how can I fix it

Thanks.

I managed to get it working by addi g the code from here

https://github.com/TheInvader360/tutorial-libgdx-google-ads/blob/9a4c9342d98c02e3c44e0b62fcfaa153d257130a/tutorial-libgdx-google-ads-android/src/com/theinvader360/tutorial/libgdx/google/ads/MainActivity.java

The code from the other site kept on crashing the game for some reason

Comment: Red squiggly lines means it doesn't compile. Probably because it can't find it. Maybe because R.layout.main_activity (no s)?

Comment: Can you post more of your code and file names?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use an interface to show/hide ads as done [here in the official guide](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Admob-in-libgdx#control)

You can still follow [the official guide](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Admob-in-libgdx) to place ads in the game. The changes you'll need to make in your MainActivity class are:

Change the lines:

```
 AdView adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, "xxxxxxxx"); // Put in your adunit ID here
 adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());
```

to:

```
AdView adView = new AdView(activity);
adView.setAdUnitId("xxxxxxx");
adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
adView.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder()
.build());
```

Modify the adParams (to make the ad appear at the bottom of screen):

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams adParams = 
            new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        adParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
        adParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
```

And in your manifest file,

Change:

```
<activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"/>
```

to:

```
<activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"/>
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
           android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a step by step, up to date,  tutorial provided by LibGDX to integrate admob in the game

https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Admob-in-libgdx